# HTTP: Error receiving data – Connection reset by peer

Tags: mongodb, monit

Since I’ve rebooted my server yesterday I’m getting this error:

mongodb’ failed protocol test [HTTP] at [localhost]:27017/ [TCP/IP] – HTTP: Error receiving data – Connection reset by peer

‘mongodb’ start: ‘/usr/bin/sudo mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb’

Tried a couple of thing but no luck.

Also checked with curl -v localhost:27017 and output below:

Rebuilt URL to: localhost:27017/
Trying ::1…
TCP_NODELAY set
connect to ::1 port 27017 failed: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1…
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 27017 (#0)
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:27017
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: /

Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
stopped the pause stream!
Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Any input or help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your mongo server is running on a different port then 27017? Try

> netstat -an |egrep -i "Proto|mongo"

Answer (score 0):

for temporary solution try to use VPN

Comment: Thanks but want it fixed permanently, any ideas what I can do?